# How to take max value from one column for each value in second column in table with many other columns in SAS Enterprise Guide?

Tags: group-by, sas, max, enterprise-guide, 4gl

I have table in SAS Enterprise Guide like below:

COL1 - date
COL2 - numeric

```
COL1      | COL2  | COL3  | COL4 | COL5
--------- |-------|-------|------|-------
01APR2021 | 11    | XXX   | XXX  | XXX
01MAY2021 | 5     | XXX   | XXX  | XXX
01MAY2021 | 25    | XXX   | XXX  | XXX
01JUN2021 | 10    | XXX   | XXX  | XXX
...       | ...   | ...   | ...  | ...
```

- And I need to for each dates in COL1 select max value in COL2.
- Moroever, in output I need to have also rest of my columns: COL3, COL4, COL5

So as a result I need somethin like below, because for date 01MAY2021 in COL1, in COL2 are two values and 25>5.

```
COL1      | COL2  | COL3  | COL4 | COL5
--------- |-------|-------|------|-------
01APR2021 | 11    | XXX   | XXX  | XXX
01MAY2021 | 25    | XXX   | XXX  | XXX
01JUN2021 | 10    | XXX   | XXX  | XXX
...       | ...   | ...   | ...  | ...
```

How can I do that in SAS Enterprise Guide ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a `GROUP BY COL1` clause in order to compute `MAX(COL2)` within the group, and also a `HAVING` clause to select the rows with the aggregate computation.  Note, there might be two rows with the same max, and thus you will get both in your result set.

Example:

```
  create table want_table as
  select * from have_table
  group by COL1
  having COL2 = max(COL2)
  ;
```